# Parsing json trying to get value

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing

I am trying to get the value *"aaG40a2f-53d3-8f74-3c200403223"* from the json code below that's in **json**.

My vb.net code looks like this:

```
For Each Row In json("data")("records")("Form")
   Try
      For rowNum = 0 To result_RowNames.Length - 1
         result_rowData(intX) = NullSafeSelect(Row, result_RowNames(rowNum))

         Select Case result_RowProperTypes(rowNum)
             Case "textField"
                _tmpHtml += "<td>" & vbCrLf
                _tmpHtml += "<input type=""text"" " & _
                                   "data-first=""yes"" " & _
                                   "data-uid=""" & NullSafeSelect(Row("@uid"), result_RowNames(rowNum)) & """ " & _
                                   "onchange=""updateChange(this);"" " & _
                                   "id=""textbox_" & rowNum & """ " & _
                                   "class=""form-control small"" " & _
                                   "value=""" & result_rowData(intX) & """>" & vbCrLf
             ......etc etc...
```

My json in ("data")("records")("Form") looks like this:

```
{
  "@application_uid": "af74c279-4340-8441-2dR4e696gb1",
  "@draft_ownerid": "",
  "@flowState": "ST_NewName",
  "@has_draft": "",
  "@id": "63",
  "@uid": "aaG40a2f-53d3-8f74-3c200403223",
  "F_FName": "test1",
  "F_LName": "test2"
}
```

The code above works - it just does not produce a value for **uid** as seen below in the output of HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-first="yes" data-uid="" onchange="updateChange(this);" id="textbox_0" class="form-control small" value="test1">
```

Comment: So, what's the question? Does your code work? If not, do you get an error? What does `Row("@uid")` return? Where's your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: we have no idea which deserialization method you used, but `json("@uid")` works for me.  I'd fix the names if you want to access them as a class object (get rid of "@")

Comment: Thanks! I suggest that you create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): Drop all the web stuff and create a single, simple command line application that takes your example json and tries to extract @uid out of it. If that doesn't work, post the complete code (which should be very small) here. If it does work, you are one step closer to solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like all I needed to do was just to use

```
Dim tmpUID = Row("@uid").ToString
```

in order to get the value I was looking for.